# Converting a class interface into a class template

Tags: c++

I'm working through some old exam papers without the memos. I just want to make sure I am understanding this correctly.

> Provide an interface of the template class

```
Dictionary <Tkey, TValue>
```

This is the scenario provided

```
class Dictionary {
    public:
        Dictionary();
        void Add(int key, const string &value);
        string Find (int key) const;
    private:
        vector<int> Keys;
        vector <string> Values;
};
```

This is the solution I have written down

```
class Dictionary {
    public:
        Dictionary();
        void Add(TKey key, const TValue &value);
        TValue Find (TKey key) const;
    private:
        vector <Dictionary> Keys;
        vector <Dictionary> Values;
};
```

This appears correct to me. I haven't compiled a driver program for this as I just want to make sure I am understand this correctly given the template class.

I think just the last 2 lines where vector is concerned is what I want to make sure I've written correctly.

Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: the `Dictionary` cannot have a member vector of `Dictionary`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply follow your instructions:

```
template<typename Tkey, typename TValue> // <<<<<<<<
class Dictionary {
public:
    Dictionary();
    void Add(TKey key, const TValue &value);
    TValue Find (TKey key) const;
private:
    vector <TKey> Keys; // <<<<<<<<
    vector <TValue> Values; // <<<<<<<
};
```

Or even better (since it's going to be hard to associate those vector members appropriately):

```
template<typename Tkey, typename TValue> // <<<<<<<<
class Dictionary {
public:
    Dictionary();
    void Add(TKey key, const TValue &value);
    TValue Find (TKey key) const;
private:
    vector <std::pair<TKey,TValue>> dict; // <<<<<<<
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This conversion is incomplete, and slightly incorrect.

To make it complete, make sure the class is actually a class template, i.e. there is

```
template <typename TKey, typename TValue>
class Dictionary {
    ...
};
```

The correction is to make the two vectors take keys and values. Currently, both vectors are set to store `Dictionary` elements, which is not what you need: the first vector should hold `TKey` elements, while the second one should hold `TValue`s. You would discover this shortcoming as soon as you'd start implementing your `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>::Find` method.